# Subtracting data between features using ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, arctoolbox, arcgis-10.6

I have a layer that contains feature classes that store optimal elevation & existing elevation values for a place. Right now the existing and optimal are stored in different features under the same layer, yellow is existing and red is optimal.

Is there a good tool or method to group them into pairs because I need to subtract the existing from the optimal to create a feature or a field with the result?

I was going to modify the Python script of the Intersect tool and use a higher cluster tolerance to group the features and subtract them.

Attribute Table

```
ID  Elev_Value  Elev_type
1   69.5         Optimal
2   69.3         Optimal
3   70.1         Existing
4   70.7         Existing
5   70.2         Optimal
6   74.3         Existing
7   73           Optimal
8   77           Existing
9   75           Optimal
10  69.5         Optimal
```

[image: Plane]

Comment: What about the existing in lower left? are you intending to subtract it from the surround 3 optimal values, you need to define a rule set on how to associate a yellow to a red, is it 1 to 1 or simply nearest?

Comment: Yes, I plan to subtract it to the surrounding three I basically want to find a way of how to link them together (Existing to optimal). I've been thinking about a rule that allows me to link them together without a lot of human intervention but I have been unlucky due to the variation that you see on the data provided in the pic above.

Comment: How about running the Generate NEAR Table tool? You would be asking to find the nearest yellow point for all red points, with the table of ID's generated you simply join their values and do the subtraction. You will probably need to separate the points out into two datasets, optimal and existing. Then run the near tool.